# MySql: the rules that define the values?

Tags: php, mysql

Can anyone explain in plain english of MySql. The rules that define the values?

Comment: I don't understand the question.

Comment: Does this link help? http://www.tutorialspoint.com/mysql/mysql-data-types.htm

Comment: This is what I was asked that is why I posted it here because I don't understand myself and I'm sure some good people can answer better.

Comment: There is no need to put -1 above?

Comment: If you read through the documentation until you get to a specific point you don't understand, you can post a question and people might be able to help. An example of a specific question would be "How do you limit the number of letters you can put in a varchar field? I read the documentation at [link] but I don't understand where you set the field size." With your current question we have no way of knowing what you didn't understand, so it's impossible for someone to try to clarify it.

Comment: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/data-types.html ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you mean the data types?

You can see them here:

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/data-types.html

See here for the summary of data types:

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/data-type-overview.html

> 11.1. Data Type Overview
>   11.1.1. Numeric Type Overview
>   11.1.2. Date and Time Type Overview
>   11.1.3. String Type Overview
>   11.1.4. Data Type Default Values

Comment: What, you want me to do your research for you? :P I added the overview link, where they've summarised it for you in the shortest way possible.

Comment: That not what I mean, if i ask a question and can answer in own words.

Comment: @Irishgirl:  If someone has asked you to put this into your own words, then isn't that something **you** should be doing after undertaking sufficient research to understand the answer?  What would anyone gain from doing it for you?

Comment: mmm good answer. I've searched the internet and quite a lot are technical that require time to do research.